# PHP errors Undefined index

Tags: php, forms, undefined-index

so I have a form and some php code to enter info in the database. However when i run the php file i get these errors:

> *Notice: Undefined index: first in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\insert.php on line 24*
>
> *Notice: Undefined index: last in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\insert.php on line 25*
>
> *Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\insert.php on line 26*
>
> *Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\insert.php on line 27*
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'first' cannot be null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\insert.php:29 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\insert.php(29): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\temp\insert.php on line 29

here is my html form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <label for="first" >Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" />
    <label for="last" >Surname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" />
    <label for="email" >   Email: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message"> Enter your question here and we will get back
    to you as soon as possible </textarea>
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

and here is my php:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully <br />";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $query=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts (first, last, email, message) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
    $query->bindParam(1, $first);
    $query->bindParam(2, $last);
    $query->bindParam(3, $email);
    $query->bindParam(4, $message);

    $first=$_POST['first'];
    $last=$_POST['last'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];

    $query->execute();

    $conn = null;

    echo 'Hi '.$_POST['first'].' ' .$_POST['last'] .' thanks for your interest.</br>';
    echo 'We will contact you at '. $_POST['email'].' soon.</br>';
?>
```

Comment: From where do you take POST parameters in-order to pass to your query ?

Comment: Presumably you are not requesting your `insert.php` page via POST. You must submit your form in order for the `$_POST` array to be populated

Comment: @BRjava lines 24 through 27

Comment: First you have to define the variables. otherwise those variables are undefined . Define $first=$_POST['first']; 
$last=$_POST['last']; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$message=$_POST['message']; before binding to the query

Comment: @BRjava can we please stop this nonsense. There's been two incorrect answers already with this same misconception. [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.bindparam.php) ~ *"the variable is **bound as a reference** and will **only be evaluated** at the time that `PDOStatement::execute()` is called"*

Comment: @Phil : can you run the code and see for your self. And try defining variables before you accessing the in the bindings. That way you will see for your self. Or use a basic IDE

Comment: @BRjava I suggest you try reading some manuals instead. Start here and pay particular attention to *Example #1* ~ http://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: how are you using variable in bindParam method before declaring it?

Comment: @ParitoshMahale **please** read some [documentation](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.bindparam.php) as well as the previous comments on this question

Comment: @Stavros Kasapi , I think you are running the insert.php drectly.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: just recognized that you need to check `isset` only :) thanks to @phil

try this code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 echo "Connected successfully <br />";
 }
catch(PDOException $e)
 {
 echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }



$query=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts (first, last, email, message) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$query->bindParam(1, $first);
$query->bindParam(2, $last);
$query->bindParam(3, $email);
$query->bindParam(4, $message);

 $first=isset($_POST['first'])?$_POST['first']:"";
$last=isset($_POST['last'])?$_POST['last']:"";
$email=isset($_POST['email'])?$_POST['email']:"";
$message=isset($_POST['message'])?$_POST['message']:"";
$query->execute();

$conn = null;

echo 'Hi '.$_POST['first'].' ' .$_POST['last'] .' thanks for your interest.</br>';
echo 'We will contact you at '. $_POST['email'].' soon.</br>';
?>
```

Comment: `bindParam` binds to a variable reference. It does not have to be set at the time of binding

Comment: nope :/ same errors

Comment: ok with help of @Phil i Edited the post :) check the new code

Comment: With the way OP is apparently executing this code, they will end up with a bunch of empty rows in their DB

Comment: Yeah maybe some problem in naming HTML form inputs...

Comment: No, more like OP is requesting `insert.php` via GET, not POST